# When disconnecting or connecting G700 via cable I can't left click

Tags: usb, logitech-mouse

I've recently invested in a Logitech G700, which runs either wirelessly or via a usb cable. The mouse is working fine, it's a sterling piece of gear.

The problem occurs when you 'hot swap' the mouse. For example, usually I have it wireless via the dongle. It works fine. Now say I want to charge it, I just attach the cable and Windows 7 has a little jitter and I hear my 'You just connected a USB device' ping. A second later I can move my mouse pointer again.

However I can't left click on any items. At first this happened in Chrome and I thought I'll close down some apps, and it looked like the cursor was locked into that app. However on further experimentation it seems that it prevents a left click on anything, even desktop icons.

I get similar behaviour if I disconnect the mouse from the cable to use wirelessly.

My SetPoint is setup to only use the 'General' profile, and I don't have any auto-switching turned on. There is a similar issue here with no solution, http://forums.logitech.com/t5/G-series-Gaming-Mice/Left-mouse-click-issues-w-G700-USB-connection-connected-amp/td-p/717234

Does anyone have any idea's or things that I could try? Currently I have to reboot my machine each time I attach or disconnect the cable from the mouse, which is hardly ideal.

Firmware: **22.37**
SetPoint: **5.46.10**
Driver: **5.33.14**

Comment: I still have this problem on occasion... rebooting is the only thing that resolves it for me. did you ever find a real solution?

Comment: @rev Not that I recall. My mouse died at a lan party in the end, so got replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I lose mouse function altogether and have restarted my machine at times in the past when I forgot that the mouse has independant power. Try this: Turn mouse power button OFF. Remove the associated usb. Place desired usb into computer. Turn bottom back into the ON position. In a moment function should restore. This works for me when going from dongle to wired and vice versa.